# How to clear all the session variables when i am logging out in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to Asp.Net Mvc4. I want to clear all the session variables when i am logging out. I am using this code. But it is not working.Please help me out to get it. Thanks in advance.

My controller code:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Clear();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps the Session is gone after you sign out.  Try to clean the session before calling SignOut?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cookies too:

```
// clear authentication cookie
HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

// clear session cookie
HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
```